# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\Desktop\\python-leakage-detection\\the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use Panda to read excel file.
I imported the panda library :`import panda as pd`,
Then, I tried to read excel file using panda ：`pressure_simulation=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Ziyuan\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx')` or `pressure_simulation=pd.read_excel('the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx')`,
it always returned the error shown below:

```
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-786c357dee31> in <module>
----> 1 pressure_simulation=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Ziyuan\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx')
      2 pressure_simulation

~\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1069                 ext = "xls"
   1070             else:
-> 1071                 ext = inspect_excel_format(
   1072                     content=path_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options
   1073                 )

~\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in inspect_excel_format(path, content, storage_options)
    947     assert content_or_path is not None
    948 
--> 949     with get_handle(
    950         content_or_path, "rb", storage_options=storage_options, is_text=False
    951     ) as handle:

~\Desktop\python-leakage-detection\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    649         else:
    650             # Binary mode
--> 651             handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
    652         handles.append(handle)
    653 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ziyuan\\Desktop\\python-leakage-detection\\the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx'
```

Could you please give me some ideas to fix this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: That file does not exist in that location. I do not know what you want us to do.

Comment: Actually, this file exist in that location. And when I used panda to read other excel files in the same location, it worked. So I do not know why I can not read this file using pandas.

Comment: Actually, the file name `'the_simulation_of_pressure.xlsx'` does not exist. Check the spelling, check for leading spaces, use glob to get the file names for all the excel files in that directory, etc.

Comment: I assume you have checked that the file really exists and is correctly spelled, etc, as suggested in comments above. Should be the first things to check. Reason I believe there might be some other error is that I have just started experciencing the same type of error with pandas and loading/saving excel files, with code that used to work (now works intermittently). Can you reliably reproduce this error? Does it work for other files, folders? Does it help with restarting? Loading another python version?